# Python3: Object won't take parameters

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am working through reviewing a video on Lynda and sometimes instead of just running the provided code I typed it myself.

The instructor's code works, but mine doesn't.

It returns `"object does not take parameters"`.

Mine is on top, his is on the bottom.

Can anyone explain?

```
    class Fibonnacci():
        def _init_(self, a, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b

        def series(self):
            while(True):
                yield(self.b)
                self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b

    f = Fibonnacci(0, 1)
    for r in f.series():
        if r > 100: break
        print(r, end=' ')
```

---

```
    class Fibonacci():
        def __init__(self, a, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b

        def series(self):
            while(True):
                yield(self.b)
                self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b

    f = Fibonacci(0, 1)
    for r in f.series():
        if r > 100: break    
        print(r, end=' ')
```

Comment: `def _init_(self, a, b):` should have double underscores: `def __init__(self, a, b):` in order to be called when the object is initialized.

Comment: just go through [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__). Init is dunder method. It is a constructor for class. but your function "_init_" which having only single underscore both sides of word `init`. It is a major reason. If you have single "_" on both sides of your `init` method it means it is not a constructor. it is your custom method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the `init` function in the class. The way this method works as seen [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) to let an object be assigned parameters when initialized. I am sure you understand this, but the simple error you made was that it requires `2` underscores on either side to take effect. Like this: `__init__`. That is the difference between your two codes.

```
class Fibonnacci():
    def _init_(self, a, b):   #<-- the error is here, should be __init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def series(self):
        while(True):
            yield(self.b)
            self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b

f = Fibonnacci(0, 1)
for r in f.series():
    if r > 100: break
    print(r, end=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even see that until you pointed it out to me.

Comment: @OphA Your welcome, but please leave an upvote and accept the answer rather than commenting :) thanks